# clearRect() works strangely

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

ClearRect works in a strange way; I was trying to refresh the canvas but it did not work with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Crypt </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border-style: dashed;"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var can     =   document.getElementById("canvas")               ,
            ctx     =   can.getContext("2d")                            ,
            posX    =   0                                               ,
            posY    =   0                                               ;

        function game(){ // HERE
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
            ctx.rect(posX, posY, 20, 20);
            ctx.stroke();

            posX += 10;
            posY += 10;
        }

        window.setInterval("game()", 100);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

works perfectly with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Crypt </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border-style: dashed;"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var can     =   document.getElementById("canvas")               ,
            ctx     =   can.getContext("2d")                            ,
            posX    =   0                                               ,
            posY    =   0                                               ;

        function game(){    // HERE
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
            ctx.strokeRect(posX, posY, 20, 20);

            posX += 10;
            posY += 10;
        }

        window.setInterval("game()", 100);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is someone able to explain ? Thank you
I don't really understand how javascript works so if you've some lectures, i'll take it

Thank you ^2

Comment: what doesn't work about it?

Comment: The first sample of code don't clear the canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is not with `clearRect()` but that you always call `ctx.rect()` on the same Path object.

To avoid it, you have to call [`ctx.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) at each new drawing :

```js
var can = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = can.getContext("2d"),
  posX = 0,
  posY = 0;

function game() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

  // create a new Path2d
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.rect(posX, posY, 20, 20);
  ctx.stroke();

  posX += 10;
  posY += 10;
}

window.setInterval(game, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border-style: dashed;"></canvas>
```

Or alternatively, you could call `ctx.strokeRect()` which does handle the `ctx.beginPath();`, `ctx.rect();` and `ctx.stroke();` in a single method.

```js
var can = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = can.getContext("2d"),
  posX = 0,
  posY = 0;

function game() { // HERE
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

  ctx.strokeRect(posX, posY, 20, 20);

  posX += 10;
  posY += 10;
}

window.setInterval(game, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border-style: dashed;"></canvas>
```